# Is it an error in my class? MySql connection isn't working properly [Visual C#]

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

Okay, I'm trying to make a simple project for school, in which the teacher is letting us use the root user so we connect to databases everything. But while compiling, there seems to be an error in my class I use to connect to MySql:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BuscarDatos
{
    class ClaseConectar
    {
        public static MySqlConnection obtener_conexion()
        {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder c = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            c.Server = "localhost";
            c.UserID = "root";
            c.Password = "*******"; //password
            c.Database = "proyecto_almacen"; //my database name already created

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'xxxxxxxxxx' (using password: NO)'
```

Also, I changed it to MySqlConnection since I got an error before in another class, about how I couldn't convert MySql into Sql only. Here's an example of the class I changed it for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace BuscarDatos
{
    class Agregar
    {
        public static int AddName (string pNombre,string pAp_paterno, string pAp_materno, string pMatricula, 
            string pDireccion, string pTelefono)
        {
            int resultado = 0;
            MySqlConnection con = ClaseConectar.obtener_conexion();
            MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into maestros (nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, matricula," +
                "direccion, telefono) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", pNombre, pAp_paterno, pAp_materno,
                pMatricula, pDireccion, pTelefono), con);
            resultado = Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return resultado;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving the connection any connection string. It doesn't know what to open.

When you create the `MysqlConnectionStringBuilder` it is completely separate from the `MySqlConnection` you create. You must use them together:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(c.ConnectionString);
```

This way you're actually giving the generated connection string to the connection object.